# How to configure Termux APT repositories in Debian?

Tags: debian, apt, repository, gpg, termux

I'm interested to configure the Termux repositories on a Debian system. However I got stuck on some point. *Any* help would be appreciated.

### Premise

My scenario is as follows. I have an Android device running the Debian-alike Linux environment emulator [Termux](https://wiki.termux.com/wiki/Main_Page) employing the package manager [APT](https://wiki.debian.org/Apt). Out of security reasons the device is [airgapped](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Air_gap_(networking)), so packages can not be retrieved from [Termux' remote repositories](https://github.com/termux/termux-packages/wiki/Mirrors) but have to be installed locally.

To bring the necessary `.deb` files onto this device I therefore have to use an intermediate machine with online access to Termux' repositories. The packages needed would be downloaded there, but not installed, and than transferred to the target device.

Obviously, the simple solution would be to use another Android device. However, for now I am bound to a PC running the minimalistic Debian-derivate [AntiX 22](https://antixlinux.com/) (matching Debian 11) in the core flavor.

Note, that [Termux is not FHS compliant](https://wiki.termux.com/wiki/Differences_from_Linux) and therefore the usual Debian or Ubuntu repositories cannot be used.

### Aim

To configure the Termux repository resp. one of its mirrors on a machine running Debian or a Debian-derivate, esp. AntiX.

### Steps

I aimed at [Grimler's mirror](https://github.com/termux/termux-packages/wiki/Mirrors#mirrors-by-grimler) as it was recommended in various situations. Any other server would be fine, too.

According to the Debian documentation's [Instructions to connect to a third-party repository](https://wiki.debian.org/DebianRepository/UseThirdParty), Ubuntu's documentation article on [Third party repository usage](https://ubuntu.com/server/docs/third-party-apt-repositories) and various other sources, inter alia this [Stackoverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71384057) one has basically 4 steps to go:

1. Fetch the GPG key for the Termux repository
2. List the repo in an APT source file
3. Run `apt update` to integrate the repo
4. Configure the repo's pinning

Note: `apt-key` is deprecated, however I tried also that. If one can show me the way employing `apt-key`, I won't mind, but that can only be an interim solution.

### Problem

No matter what I try, I get stuck on step 3, when `apt` tells me:

```
Err https://grimler.se/termux-main stable InRelease
The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY 5A897D96E57CF20C
```

### Approaches

I combined variations for steps 1-3.

##### Tinkering on the GPG file

I tried the [`termux-keyring`](https://grimler.se/termux-main/pool/main/t/termux-keyring/) package first. As mentioned one can't install it directly to a Debian system, so I took it apart, and placed all files manually into the right places. The public GPG files into `/usr/share/termux-keyring/`, resp. in another try in the already existing `/usr/share/keyrings/`. I also accordingly placed the symlinks -- in another try the files themselves -- into `/etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d/` pointing to these GPG files.

As it is actually not recommended to put something into `/etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d/` I than removed the symlinks resp. the GPG files from there. Only `/usr/share/keyrings/` has been used further.

Getting paranoia that I'm using the wrong key files I also tried to use the public keys from [Grimler's homepage](https://grimler.se/pubkey/raw) and [Repository](https://grimler.se/termux-main/dists/stable) but without change. Dearmoring and armoring also yields nothing.

##### The list file

My `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/grimler.list` just contains the line

```
deb [signed-by=/usr/share/keyrings/grimler.gpg] https://grimler.se/termux-main stable main
```

Leaving out the `signed-by` doesn't change anything, which I actually consider to be strange. Changing `https` to `http` makes no difference, too.

##### Finding the unfound public key

To solve the error message

```
Err https://grimler.se/termux-main stable InRelease
The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY 5A897D96E57CF20C
```

I naturally tried to solve the problem with

```
$ gpg --no-default-keyring --keyring grimler.gpg --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv-keys 5A897D96E57CF20C
```

and

```
$ apt-key adv --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv-keys 5A897D96E57CF20C
```

and similar. Alas, though the key has been imported, the error message remained.

### Summary

So, how do I configure a Termux repository in Debian? Esp.

- Which keys do I have to use from where, and where to put them? Do they have to be modified in some way?
- Is something missing in the source file?
- How to feed APT the public key `5A897D96E57CF20C`?

Thanks in advance for your time and any helpful advice. Feel free to ask or comment, if need be I'll add further information.

Comment: Fingerprint of `grimler.gpg` is `B0076E490B71616B` which is different from the `5A897D96E57CF20C`. The correct key seems to be https://keyserver.ubuntu.com/pks/lookup?op=get&search=0xcc72cf8ba7dbfa0182877d045a897d96e57cf20c.

Comment: Alas, using this key, whether armored or dearmored, also results in the same above mentioned error -- `The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY 5A897D96E57CF20C`.

Comment: that's weird. i did added `deb [signed-by=/tmp/lookup.asc] https://grimler.se/termux-main stable main`, where `lookup.asc`  key with fingerprint `5A897D96E57CF20C` and it works.

Comment: Thx, that was indeed helpful. It turns out that the file extension `.asc` was expected. The error now disappeared, however I get a new one: `Unknown error executing apt-key`. Very informative message.